# Usar parámetro en un TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM USUARIOS
```

la quiero pasar a un SP de esta manera:

```
DECLARE @TOP INT
SET @TOP = 10

SELECT TOP @TOP * FROM USUARIOS
```

> Incorrect syntax near '@TOP'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que te aconsejaría es no llamar a tus variables/parámetros con nombres reservados por SQL Server.

Para lograr lo que planteas, solo tienes que hacer *(Nota: Esto solo funciona para SQL Server 2005 en adelante)*:

```
DECLARE @TopVariable INT = 10

SELECT TOP (@TopVariable) * FROM USUARIOS -- Notese los paréntesis en la consulta.
```

Lo agregarias a tu SP de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TraerNUsuarios](@TopVariable INT) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@TopVariable) * FROM USUARIOS;
END
```

Para versiones anteriores a SQL Server 2005, puedes utilizar:

```
DECLARE @TopVariable INT
SET @TopVariable = 10
SET ROWCOUNT @TopVariable

SELECT * FROM USUARIOS
```

Y lo agregarías al SP cambiando todo lo que está dentro del `BEGIN` y `END`.

Referencia: [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175962/5622844).